# NPM peer Dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, package.json

I'm at the moment upgrading from Angular 4 to Angular 5 and received some warnings after that, for example:

```
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @covalent/core@1.0.0-beta.8-1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @covalent/core@1.0.0-beta.8-1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @covalent/core@1.0.0-beta.8-1 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @covalent/core@1.0.0-beta.8-1 requires a peer of @angular/http@^4.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @covalent/core@1.0.0-beta.8-1 requires a peer of @angular/router@^4.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @covalent/core@1.0.0-beta.8-1 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@^2.0.0-beta.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @covalent/core@1.0.0-beta.8-1 requires a peer of @angular/material@^2.0.0-beta.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myAngularProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@covalent/core": "^1.0.0-beta.8-1",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/core": "^1.4.34",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/ui-material": "^1.4.34",
    "ag-grid": "^13.3.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^13.3.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "install-peers": "^1.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  },
}
```

My question is now, how do I add those peer dependencies manually and where? I've searched for ways to add them automatically but they do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:**

You don't have to add any peer dependencies, yourself. The message is only displaying that you have unmet dependencies, and I believe you can continue using @covalent package unless something breaks as these are warnings.

This seems to be an issue with the package `@covalent` as it depends upon `@angular4` and it's respective packages and appears to be incompatible . Since there are few breaking changes from angular4 and angular5. So this is an expected behavior. 
You have two options now precisely:

1. Submit PR to the said [repository](https://github.com/Teradata/covalent), so you can get a fix asap.
2. Wait for @covalent to release an update for `@angular5`, and once the update is out, you can safely update both `@angular4` itself and `@covalent` as well.